# XCode: duplicate symbol error when using global variable

Tags: c++, xcode, duplicates

Here's my code:

A.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int bar;
};

Foo myFoo;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
int main()
{
    myFoo.bar = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Xcode gives me the error (paraphrased):

```
duplicate symbol _myFoo in main.o & A.o
```

I'd like to keep the `Foo myFoo` within the A.h file.

So why is XCode throwing this error and how can I rectify it?

Comment: For your next question, please show *all* the code necessary to reproduce. Where does A.o come from? That's our only hint that you have a second translation unit, which is crucial here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define the global variable in header and it breaks the **[one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**.
Each TU where you include the header will have its own copy of the object.

You need to use `extern` keyword:

1. Declare the object as extern in header.
2. Define it one and only one source file.
3. Include the header wherever you want to use the global variable

---

**A.h**

```
extern Foo myFoo;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

Foo myFoo;
```

**XXXX.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"
```

Answer (score 3):

`Foo myFoo;` is a **definition**, not a declaration. Use `extern Foo myFoo;` for a declaration and move the definition in a single implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `No Common Blocks` set to No in build Settings.